# Can user disable sharedobjects in flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex3, flex4.5

Can user disable SharedObjects in flex, just like as they do in case of cookies? 
And flex application can always store sharedobjects successfully in user's pc without getting any access denied error? I
f this is the case will flex application will just ignore creating sharedobjects instead of throwing error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the user can disable on a particular website or even in a global way. If you try to flush a SharedObject in a restricted environment you wil get an error:

```
Error: #2130: Unable to flush SharedObject
```

However you can query the flush status response too see if the object has been created:

```
status = my_sharedobject.flush();
```

And look if it is `SharedObjectFlushStatus.PENDING or SharedObjectFlushStatus.FLUSHED`.

Edit

I found an answered question that could help you more than I tried:

[Flex: How to detect if user has blocked shared object from writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253444/flex-how-to-detect-if-user-has-blocked-shared-object-from-writing)