# Flex: NetStatusEvent not fired by Local Shared Object. Why?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

This is what I do: In the 'Local Storage' dialog I set the pointer to 'None' to allow 0 kB. Then I run my code. I get the 'Local Storage' dialog with an [Allow] and [Deny] button. I click [Deny]

The output I get is

```
2. we are here now
3. adding a handler to the SharedObject
```

NOTE: The onFlushStatus event handler is NOT called.

I repeat the above stuff, but now click [Allow].
The output I get is the same:

```
2. we are here now
3. adding a handler to the SharedObject
```

NOTE: The onFlushStatus event handler is NOT called.

I was using the code from here
[Flex: How to detect if user has blocked shared object from writing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253444/flex-how-to-detect-if-user-has-blocked-shared-object-from-writing)

Whatever I try (and I tried much), the event handler gets never called on a [Allow] or [Deny] button click. But I want to know which button the user clicked.

```
var so: SharedObject = null;
var flushStatus: String = null;

so = SharedObject.getLocal('mySpace');
try {
  flushStatus = so.flush();
} catch (error: Error) {
  trace('1. could not write SharedObject to disk');
}           
trace('2. we are here now');
if (flushStatus == flash.net.SharedObjectFlushStatus.PENDING) {
  trace('3. adding a handler to the SharedObject');
  so.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onFlushStatus);
} 

public function onFlushStatus(event: NetStatusEvent): void
{
  trace('4. in event handler');
}
```

As suggested I changed my code and added the event listener before calling flush(). Then I run my tests again. Unfortunately my onFlushStatus() is not called.

```
var so: SharedObject = null;
var flushStatus: String = null;

so = SharedObject.getLocal('mySpace');
trace('0. adding a handler to the SharedObject');
so.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, onFlushStatus);
flushStatus = so.flush();
trace('2. we are here now');

public function onFlushStatus(event: NetStatusEvent): void
{
  trace('4. in event handler');
}
```

The output I get for [Deny]

```
0. adding a handler to the SharedObject
2. we are here now
```

The output I get for [Allow]

```
0. adding a handler to the SharedObject
2. we are here now
```

The onFlushStatus() is not called.

Comment: I guess add a listener prior to flushing, and trace then.

Comment: I did this in the past already and did it again right now, to be sure. But the event handler is not called.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm hitting the exact same wall and the documentation just seems wrong.

Answer (score 0):

From [this](http://livedocs.adobe.com/livecycle/es/sdkHelp/common/langref/flash/net/SharedObject.html#flush%28%29) link it appears that `so.flush` is returning a `String` with the result of the `flush()` command. Rather than looking for an event to be fired you should look at the value of the return. If it's a `pending` then add your event listener and check success/fail.

A good example: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253444/flex-how-to-detect-if-user-has-blocked-shared-object-from-writing)